# Does an image gallery slideshow/carousel need a pause button to be accessible?

Tags: javascript, carousel, accessibility, slideshow, wcag

I'm trying to understand the WCAG accessibility guidelines for slideshows and carousels presented here: [What Makes a Carousel Accessible?](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/carousels/)

Specifically I'm unsure about the case where the carousel displays changing images and not textual information. In this case does it still require a pause / play button?

For example does the carousel on the homepage of [this website](https://www.deadseascrolls.org.il/home) require a pause / play button to be considered accessible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in order to meet WCAG2.0 criteria [2.2.2 Pause, Stop, Hide (Level A)](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/time-limits-pause.html) you will need to allow the user to pause the carousel, regardless of whether the slides contain any textual information. If the movement lasts for longer than 5 seconds (which it likely will assuming it's a non-stop looping carousel), users must be able to pause it.

If you read the Understanding 2.2.2 (hyperlink in previous paragraph) it mentions:

> The intent of this Success Criterion is to avoid distracting users during their interaction with a Web page.
>
> "Moving, blinking and scrolling" refers to content in which the visible content conveys a sense of motion. Common examples include motion pictures, synchronized media presentations, animations, real-time games, and scrolling stock tickers.
>
> Moving content can also be a severe distraction for some people. Certain groups, particularly those with attention deficit disorders, find blinking content distracting, making it difficult for them to concentrate on other parts of the Web page. Five seconds was chosen because it is long enough to get a user's attention, but not so long that a user cannot wait out the distraction if necessary to use the page.

While this is especially important if your moving slides contain information which needs to be read, it's also required for moving image-only slides for the reasons quoted above.

Answer (score 2):

> Does an image gallery slideshow/carousel need a pause button to be accessible?

Having a "pause button" is a must-have but it won't make a slideshow accessible, nor a carousel something user-friendly.

> For example does the carousel on the homepage of this website require a pause / play button to be considered accessible?

Clicking on one of the little dots in the corner do pause the animation, so it would answer to that WCAG concern if the visual cues and text alternative were more meaningful.

The problem is in fact more difficult because we have to understand different kind of user experiences :

- blind people won't perceive the carousel as an animation, adding a play/pause button does not add any value for them (nor than a "next / previous" slide indication when it was not announced that what they are listening to is a slideshow).
- visually impaired people will need more time to read so pausing is important, but the ability to pause should be announced before.

In fact not having a carousel would be the best accessibility answer. The WCAG has a [full tutorial page about carousels](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/carousels/). The most important part of it is:

> Carousels are disputed from a usability perspective because their content can be hard to discover.

Answer (score 0):

You can also fill accessibility requirements by making sure that when the user focuses into the carousel or an element in the carousel it pauses.  And then just take sure it doesn’t start back up on its own.